# Add value to a variable without creating a new variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a variable named playerGold and it starts with a value of 0. (playerGold=0).
I have this variable displayed on a label on my tkinter GUI (playerGoldLabel).

I want to make it so when I click a button it adds on 13 to the playerGold variable and updates the tkinter label.

I have tried playerGold + 13 and using playerGoldLabel.config(text=playerGold) to try and update it but it doesn't seem to work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a lack of basic understanding of what value assignation is

Comment: Apologies for the close/reopen (which I think reset the close votes...). My mouse was a few seconds ahead of my brain.

Answer (score 1):

`playerGold + 13` does not change anything. If you want to modify a variable, you will need to use `playerGold = playerGold + 13`, or shorter `playerGold += 13`.

Comment: Please only answer if your answer is a good answer.  Otherwise stick to comments to find out whether you understood the question correctly.  _This_ answer here just marks the question as answered but probably does not solve the tkinter issues OP has.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and simple answer! This solved my little problem.

Comment: @ user3654976 : please accept mdsl answer, as it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
myVar = myVar + 13
```

It's so simple I don't know if i really get your problem

Comment: Yeah, and that's why this should have been a comment, not an answer :-(  By giving fast (and perhaps useless) answers you take the focus from this question as it appears to be answered.  Many readers will not read this question anymore.

Comment: In this case it was actually simple but i get this for the next time